# Как найти в файле повторы

Tags: python, файлы, поиск

Не могу никак реализовать программу, что ищет в файле txt повторы слов и убирает их. Пытаюсь реализовать на языке Python. Алгоритм работы:

1. Пользователь вводит путь до файла.
2. Программа ищет копии слов.
3. Сохраняет перезаписанный файл.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать. Заранее буду очень благодарен.

Comment: 1. Получаете путь к файлу (например через input) 2. Открываете файл (например через with open()) 3. Считываете файл с разбивкой по словам (например через split()) 4. Ищете копии слов (непонятно во всем файле или повторяющиеся подряд, так что уточните) 5. Удаляете повторы слов (опять зависит от задачи) 6. Сохраняете полученный результат (например через тот же with open())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример не совершенен, так как полностью решить задачу нелегко. Надо удалять слова, а что делать с пробелами между ними? Или знаками препинания? Или переводами строк?

Переводы строк сохраняются, так как мы читаем и пишем файлы построчно. Пробелами внутри строк придётся пожертвовать. Между любыми двумя словами пробел будет, а пробелы вначале и в конце строк пропадут. Также длинные последовательности пробелов заменятся на одиночные. Знаки препинания приклеиваем к словам.

Обработка по строка позволит не занимать память под лишние тексты. Уже известные слова храняться в `set`: быстрый поиск и обновление.

Программа:

```
in_file = input('Входной файл: ')
out_file = input('Выходной файл: ')

words = set()

with open(in_file) as in_f:
    with open(out_file, 'w') as out_f:
        for line in in_f:
            out_words = []
            for word in line.split():
                if word not in words:
                    words.add(word)
                    out_words.append(word)
            print(' '.join(out_words), file=out_f)
```

Запускаем её на самой себе:

```
$ python remove_duplicates.py
Входной файл: remove_duplicates.py
Выходной файл: output.txt
```

Результат:

```
in_file = input('Входной файл: ')
out_file input('Выходной

words set()

with open(in_file) as in_f:
open(out_file, 'w') out_f:
for line in
out_words []
word line.split():
if not words:
words.add(word)
out_words.append(word)
print(' '.join(out_words), file=out_f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Открываем файл
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as r:
    txt = r.read().split(" ") # читаем из файла и разбиваем на слова 

result = ""
for i in txt: # Для каждого слова в txt
    if i not in result:
        result += i + " "

# Пишем в файл
with open("res.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Comment: место пустого `if` можно написать `if i not in result`

Comment: Можно но мне кажется так понятнее для новичков. Конечно же личное имхо.

Comment: @Danis — прав. Так писать — плохо. Даже для новичков.